# Error in Remix "Error from IDE : Invalid account selected"

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm new to Remix and Solidity and don't understand why I recieve error message "**Error from IDE : Invalid account selected**".
Below line is executed successfully:

```
await contract.methods.SetMaxSupply("600").send({from: accounts[0]});
```

Below line results in above mentioned error message:

```
let supply = await contract.methods.current_supply().call()
```

Solidity code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
 
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
 
 
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
 
contract Test is Ownable {
 
    uint public max_supply; 
 
     function SetMaxSupply(uint amount) public onlyOwner { 
       max_supply = amount;
   }
 
    function current_supply() public view returns(uint) {
        return max_supply * 3;
    }
 
}
```

Remix JS Script:

```
// Right click on the script name and hit "Run" to execute
(async () => {
    try {
        console.log('Running deployWithWeb3 script...')
        
        // replace with contract address
        const contractAddress = '0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138'
        
        const contractName = 'Test' // Change this for other contract
    
        // Note that the script needs the ABI which is generated from the compilation artifact.
        // Make sure contract is compiled and artifacts are generated
        const artifactsPath = `browser/contracts/StackOverflow/artifacts/${contractName}.json` // Change this for different path
        
        const metadata = JSON.parse(await remix.call('fileManager', 'getFile', artifactsPath))
        const abi = metadata.abi
        
        // instantiate a new web3 Contract object
        let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress)
        
        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
        
        await contract.methods.SetMaxSupply("600").send({from: accounts[0]});
        
        let supply = await contract.methods.current_supply().call()
        
        console.log(supply)
        
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
    }
  })()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the **Account** parameter in the **Deploy & Run Transaction**